# use ACF taxonomy field term as value of wp_query

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I'm running a wp_query on a page template in order to get posts from a custom post type "tour" filtered by a custom taxonomy "location". This taxonomy is hierachical and organised "land -> region -> spot". The current page that uses the template in question has the same taxonomy assigned by an ACF taxonomy field. This wp_query actually works fine:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'location' => 'meran' ); $featured_tour = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) : while ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) :     $featured_tour->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
        <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>No tour here! :( </p>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I would now like to replace the name of the location by the term that's selected in the ACF "spot" field, something like:  'location' => 'function_that_inserts_current_ACF_term'. 
Is there any way to retrieve this? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: `$term_field = get_field('my_taxonomy', $post->ID);` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: it's giving me a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/.../wp-content/themes/.../template-leaflet-archive.php on line 94. I was trying like so: <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'location' => '$term_field = get_field('spot', $post->ID);' ); $featured_tour = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

Comment: The `$term_field` variable and declaration shouldn't be in your `args` array. the `location` array key needs to be a string value, which is the field you get from ACF.

Comment: I'm not shure if I got you right ... could you please give me a hint of what code to use? Thank you

Comment: `<?php $your_tax = get_field('tax', $page_id);  //$page_id should be the page of 'Meran' ?>
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'location' => $your_tax ); $featured_tour = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) : while ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) :     $featured_tour->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
        <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
    </article>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>No tour here! :( </p>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` 

You are now getting the ACF tax field if it exists in your current page.

Comment: thank you very much! It's working nearby perfectly, only that I'm having now a warning that says: "Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Applications/AMPPS/www/trails_de/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3835" Any idea of what this could be?

Comment: It may be something else broken in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php $your_tax = get_field('tax', $page_id); //$page_id should be the page of 'Meran'
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'location' => $your_tax );

 $featured_tour = new WP_Query( $args ); ?> 

<?php if ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) :
 while ( $featured_tour->have_posts() ) : $featured_tour->the_post(); ?> 
<article> 
   <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1> 
</article> 
<?php endwhile; 
else : ?>
  <p>No tour here! :( </p> <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You are now getting the ACF tax field if it exists in your current page.

Comment: I tried the code in another template and it's giving me the same error: "Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /..../wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3835". Any idea of how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Well this is another question ofcourse, but can you show the code?

Comment: It's exactly the code you gave me in your answer. The code provided in my question works without errors, but is "static". The version you proposed works dynamically as intended, but wp outputs the warning.

Comment: Pretty weird. What happens if you just input a string instead of the field with this code?

Comment: Then I'm back to where I began: it's a working wp_query, static, but without throwing any error.

Comment: hmm, I'd like to help you with it. Do you mind sending the code you have from the whole page to my email in my profile? Or can you edit your first post with all your code? (from the page you used the code you already showed)